# FCM ios configuration

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use FCM for push notification . I follow the docs and I'm trying to use :

```
InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("Error fetching remote instange ID: \(error)")
    } else if let result = result {
        print("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")
        self.instanceIDTokenMessage.text  = "Remote InstanceID token: \(result.token)"
    }
}
```

as specified in the docs but I'm not sure where I should put it, should it be inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`?

I get this compilation error :

> Static member 'instanceID' cannot be used on instance of type
>   'InstanceID'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Observer in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.InstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)
}
```

Call it inside `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    self.connectToFcm()
}
```

Method

```
@objc func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    self.connectToFcm()
}
```

Create 1 function.

```
func connectToFcm() {
    InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error fetching remote instange ID: \(error)")
        }
        else {
            print("FCM Token = \(String(describing: result?.token))")
            print("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")
            self.instanceIDTokenMessage.text  = "Remote InstanceID token: \(result.token)"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @H.Epstein, Please update your pod and  try again because i used that and there's no error.

Comment: I updated the pods and that fixed the problem ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am certain that a few people coming through here and experiencing this issue are not having their problem solved by the solution given by Kuldeep.

I had the same exact issue.

Inside `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` instead of using the `InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID` as suggested by the [capacitor guide](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/push-notifications-firebase#add-initialization-code), do this.

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(CAPNotifications.DidRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken.name()), object: Messaging.messaging().fcmToken )
  }
```

The only difference from the standard `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is that we are using `Messaging.messaging().fcmToken`.

Found solution on [medium](https://medium.com/fantageek/push-notification-in-ios-with-firebase-1c25f39ca578). You would expect this or at least a working version to be on the capacitor docs... It is up to you which guide you follow, I used all of capacitors guide but needed this to test notifications with the fcmToken. The medium guide has more about the fcmToken, so, depending on your use case it may be a good idea to look into this guide.